# Install Weblogic on Fedora 19. tmp too small?

Tags: installation, fedora, fedora-19

I've been trying to work this out for a bit now and I'm getting nowhere fast. Anyone else have any success with this setup?

The issue is that there doesn't appear to be enough space in tmp. Message:

```
 ./oepe-12.1.2.1-kepler-installer-linux-gtk.bin
 0%....................................................................................................100%
 Not enough disk space in dir /tmp/sfx_2Xj7ks, requires at least - 1885 MB disk space
```

I decided to check out things - `df -h` shows this:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   35G  8.7G   25G  26% /
devtmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    2.0G  148K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    2.0G  656K  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                    2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    2.0G   20K  2.0G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M  139M  310M  31% /boot
none                     239G   79G  160G  33% /media/sf_Projects
```

tmpfs looks rather on the empty side so there should be the 1885 MB that it is requesting available. Some googling should I can D flag java.io.tmpdir to another value but I'm getting the same result even when I use my user space which has plenty free.

One solution I tried was to delete `/tmp` and softlink to `/var/tmp` just so it would have space however I can't delete `/tmp`. A process seems to be holding on for some reason.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: It appears I left out an important detail. tmpfs being too small was the barrier I was encountering. This was a VM instance. It was as easy as cranking the allotted ram above 4GB then everything started working.

Comment: You can reboot to clear `/tmp` - don't try deleting it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to install WebLogic but it fails claiming tmp is too small to unpack the install. I was going to make the tmp dir a softlink to a dir on a bigger partition so I can get the install done then put things back the way they were.

Comment: Reboot to clear `/tmp`, then try extracting it again. A machine with more `/tmp` is definitely more likely to extract it successfully (i think all mine have around 2.9GB) - I don't think you can edit `/tmp` easily on a running system, as often several processes are using it (to find them, run `lsof /tmp`). The easiest way i can think of to edit/remove `/tmp` is to only login in a TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F2), so no GUI processes like pulseaudio and gnome-shell are using it, then running `sudo umount /tmp` - this is not guaranteed to work...

Comment: Yeah, I've done that and I get the same message. Not sure why since looking at it there would still be free space but not much extra. Trying to figure out how to increase the size of that partition right now. I don't think it would hurt to increase the size. Anything that gets it installed.

Comment: Looking at the partitions I have a main partition and a boot partition so I take it that increases that partition is off the table. I guess another question is how to increase the size of tmpfs